# Error with the dialog box

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to enter a length and then set the equipament for this length. 
Could someone help me? This is what I did:

```
function [] = config_length (gpib, loop_l)
    loop.length = loop_l;
    loop.noiseA=0;
    loop.noiseB=0;
    [err]=DLS414_SetupLoop (gpib,loop)
endfunction

getLength = x_dialog(['Loop Length';'Enter the length of loop:'],'');
config_length (14, getLength)
```

I do not understand why the function `config_length` is not reading the value of getLength. And when I press cancel, the program gives me an error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [getvalue](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/getvalue.html). I think this looks better than a multiline dialog

### Working example

```
function [] = config_length (gpib, loop_l)
    loop.length = loop_l;
    loop.noiseA=0;
    loop.noiseB=0;
    printf('Config_length called with gpib %f and loop_l %d', gpib, int(loop_l));    
endfunction

[ok,loop_length]=getvalue("Enter the length of loop",["loop_length"],list("vec",1),["0"]); 
config_length(14, loop_length);
```